# C# query not translating to MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, string, visual-studio

```
String query6 = "
  SELECT p.*,SUM(L.qty)as sales 
  FROM product p,purchaseLog L 
  WHERE L.purchaseDate 
    BETWEEN '"+ startDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") + "' 
    AND '"+endDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") +"' 
    AND p.id=l.itemID GROUP BY p.product_name 
  ORDER BY sales ASC LIMIT " + " " + " " + count + "";
```

This is the query that I made in Visual Studio. I tried inputting this query manually without variables in `phpmyadmin` and it works just fine. But for some reason when I write the query down and pass it to a `mysqlcommand` and `mysqldatareader` it doesn't detect the date. The count used not work too. But adding space in between the word "limit" and the count made it work.

Is C# trimming some parts of my queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `'yyyy-dd-MM'` is the wrong format. It must be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. Ideally you'd even prefix this with the word `DATE` so as to mark the string as a date literal:

```
" ... WHERE L.purchaseDate BETWEEN DATE '" + startDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + 
                            "' AND DATE '" + endDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'... "
```

Comment: thank you it worked, I actually accidentally posted the wrong code, I did had the format yyyy-MM-dd but it was returning empty rows. I added the DATE and it now worked.